# Can solr highlight two different search terms in two different color?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am new to solr and have been asked to implement search result highlighting. My search query is something like this,

query = text like **'searchterm1'** AND **'searchterm2'**

Now I need to instruct solr to highlight **'searchterm1'**, **'searchterm2'** in **yellow** and **blue** colors respectively. Is this even possible to do with solr? and if yes how do I go about it?

This is the code snippet that is currently highlighting the search result.

```
    private AbstractSolrQuery _query = new SolrQuery(searchterm1) && new SolrQuery(searchterm2);

    public SolrQueryResults<Document> Execute(string defaultField)
    {
        var results = _solr.Query(_query, new QueryOptions
        {
            Rows = 100,
            Fields = Document.GetPropertiesExceptList(new List<string>{"text","text_exact"}).ToArray(),
            ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    { "df", defaultField },
                    { "hl.fragsize", "0" },
                    { "hl", "true" }
            }
        });

        Highlight(results);
        return results;
    }

    private void Highlight(SolrQueryResults<Document> results)
    {
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            foreach (var highlightedSnippet in results.Highlights[result.Id.ToString()])
            {
                result.SetProperty("content", highlightedSnippet.Value.ToList());
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help with this would be very much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Hello I have been trying to implement the same but it is not working for me. I tried Jayendra's solution but was unable to get desired results. Can you please let me know how did you do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check upon [hl.fragmentsBuilder](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fragmentsBuilder) which will allow you to return the snippets in different color. I am just not sure if it applies to search terms, matches or field.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following parameters into the `requestHandler` definition in `solrconfig.xml` to highlight in different color. You can set the background color as you want.

```
   <str name="hl.simple.pre">&lt;b style="background:yellow"&gt;</str>
   <str name="hl.simple.post">&lt;/b&gt;</str>
```

The full example requestHandler could be something like :

```
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="df">text</str>

     <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
       <str name="hl">on</str>
       <str name="hl.fl">*</str>
       <str name="hl.simple.pre">&lt;b style="background:yellow"&gt;</str>
       <str name="hl.simple.post">&lt;/b&gt;</str>
     </lst>
   </requestHandler>
```

For details you can check [HighlightingParameters.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters)